# ruby - averaging values to a second

Tags: ruby, csv, time, average

Got a table that contains values against time in milliseconds resolution. Is there a quick way to average all the values (after an operation) occurring in a second ?

**input table**

time , value

00:54:08.349 , 14

00:54:08.349 , 13

00:54:08.449 , 20

00:54:09.349 , 15

00:54:09.628 , 21

00:54:10.679 , 13

00:54:10.839 , 12

**output table**

time,value

00:54:08.000 ,255 (14^2 + 13^2 + 20^2)/3

00:54:09.000,333 (15^2 +21^2)/2

00:54:10.000, 156.5 (13^2 + 12^2)/2`

I'm reading the input file from a csv as a `CSV::table`, so each row can be read as `row[i] = csv[i]` and `row[i]['time']` and `row[i]['value']` are available -  would be helpful to get ideas on how to manipulate it to get an average.

Comment: So you want to average values corresponding to > 00:54:08.00 but < 00:54:09.000? Why does it look like you are averaging by squaring your values before adding them and dividing by the number of operands? Shouldn't it be `(14 + 13 + 20)/3`? What code do you have so far?

Comment: The objective is to get the per second average for values in the input table.  Ideally, all values from `00:54:07.501` to `00:54:08.499` , falls in the per second bucket for `00:54:08.000`. It is not just the average - but an operation is done on the individual values before averaging. I used `square` to just illustrate this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, assuming the array is sorted by time, as it is in the example.

**Code**

```
def avg_of_squares(a)
  a.chunk { |t,v| t[0,8] }.map { |t,v|
    [t[0,8], v.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,x)| tot + x*x }/(v.size.to_f)] }
end
```

If `a` were not sorted, first sort it on the first element:

```
a.sort_by(&:first)
```

**Example**

```
a = [["00:54:08.349", 14],
     ["00:54:08.349", 13],
     ["00:54:08.449", 20],
     ["00:54:09.349", 15],
     ["00:54:09.628", 21],
     ["00:54:10.679", 13],
     ["00:54:10.839", 12]]

avg_of_squares(a)
  #=> [["00:54:08", 255.0], ["00:54:09", 333.0], ["00:54:10", 156.5]]
```

**Explanation**

The steps:

```
e = a.chunk { |t,v| t[0,8] }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fbaac08a2f0>:each>
```

Convert the enumerator to an array to see it's contents:

```
e.to_a
  #=> [["00:54:08", [["00:54:08.349", 14], ["00:54:08.349", 13],
  #                  ["00:54:08.449", 20]]],
  #    ["00:54:09", [["00:54:09.349", 15], ["00:54:09.628", 21]]],
  #    ["00:54:10", [["00:54:10.679", 13], ["00:54:10.839", 12]]]]

f = e.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #
  #    <Enumerator::Generator:0x007fbaac08a2f0>:each>:map> 
f.to_a
  # (same as for e)
```

You can think of `f` as a "compound enumerator". Pass the first element of `f` into the block and assign the block variables:

```
t,v = f.next
  #=> ["00:54:08", [["00:54:08.349", 14], ["00:54:08.349", 13],
  #   ["00:54:08.449", 20]]] 
t 
  #=> "00:54:08" 
v
  #=> [["00:54:08.349", 14], ["00:54:08.349", 13], ["00:54:08.449", 20]]
g = v.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,x)|tot + x*x }/(v.size.to_f)
  #=> 255.0
```

so the first element of `f` is mapped to:

```
["00:54:08", 255.0]
```

The other calculations are performed similarly.